# уникальные значения в столбцах, как их выбрать?

Tags: sql

Есть таблица

```
id | hash | name_var | value
1     a      number    5
2     a      text      hello
3     b      number    5
4     b      text      goodbye
5     с      number    6
6     с      text      apple
7     d      number    6
8     d      text      orange
```

Как выбрать все hash где  number есть 5 и в text отсутствует hello?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В одно чтение это просто решается:

```
SELECT hash
FROM table
GROUP BY hash
HAVING
  --обязательно должна быть строка, где name_val='number' AND value='5'
  MAX(CASE WHEN name_val='number' AND value='5' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
  AND
  --не должно быть строки, где name_val='text' AND value='hello'
  MAX(CASE WHEN name_val='text' AND value='hello' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Причем если у некоторого hash отсутствует свойство text - запрос вернёт этот hash.
А если отсутствует свойство number - то такой hash не вернётся.
Как я понял именно так и требуется.

Answer (score 4):

```
select hash from table t1 where name_var='number' and value=5 
and not exists(select 1 from table t2 where t1.hash=t2.hash
  and t2.name_var='text' and t2.value = 'hello')
```

Comment: +1: Должен работать правильно, но `select hash` надо заменить на `select distinct hash` чтобы удовленворить условию "уникальные значения"

Comment: @Oleg Поскольку структура не описана, я исхожу из того, что дубликатов строк быть не должно. А лишняя сортировка - это потеря производительности. Так что я дистинкт ставить не буду по принципиальным соображениям. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Подойдет?

```
SELECT t1.hash
FROM table t1
JOIN table t2 ON t1.hash=t2.hash
WHERE t1.value=5 AND t1.name_var='number' AND t2.value<>'hello' AND t2.name_var='text'
GROUP BY t1.hash
```

Comment: это все одна таблица

Comment: Ну так таблицу саму с собой и объединяете.. Если таблица называется `eta_tablitsa`, то Ваш запрос будет выглядеть вот так: `SELECT t1.* FROM eta_tablitsa t1 JOIN eta_tablitsa t2 ` и т.д.

Comment: В зависимости от того, что Вам нужно - может понадобиться еще `GROUP BY `

Comment: поправил вопрос

Comment: поправил ответ.

Comment: все равно не могу сообразить что за t2, попытался через пма отправить запрос получил ошибку мол не знаю второй таблицы. Первая таблица называется `alldata`

Comment: @user193361 t2 это алиас таблицы в конкретном запросе. Имя своей таблицы пишете перед t2 вместо слова table. Т.е. `SELECT t1.hash
FROM alldata t1
JOIN alldata t2 ON t1.hash=t2.hash
WHERE t1.value=5 AND t1.name_var='number' AND t2.value<>'hello' AND t2.name_var='text'
GROUP BY t1.hash`

Comment: Это ТА ЖЕ САМАЯ ТАБЛИЦА. Она связывается сама с собой. t1 и t2 это алиас (прозвище). Можете поменять jwhiw и ogkh (на что угодно). Зато при объединении БД будет в какой из двух одинаковых таблиц искать.

Comment: а если у меня в исходней таблице три значения name_var на каждый хэш, мне ее нужно ее три раз объеденить? по каждому нужно условие соблюсти

Comment: да. Нужно объединять каждый раз. Если таких "объединений" понадобиться больше, то подумайте насчет смены структуры. Или может быть создать view, или временную таблицу... Есть несколько разных вариантов...

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table (id int, [hash] varchar(5), [name_var] varchar(20), value varchar(20))

insert into @t(id,[hash], [name_var], [value])
values(1,     'a',      'number',     '5'),
(2,     'a',      'text',       'hello'),
(3,     'b',      'number',    '5'),
(4,     'b',      'text',      'goodbye'),
(5,     'с',      'number',    '6'),
(6,     'с',      'text',      'apple'),
(7,     'd',      'number',    '6'),
(8,     'd',      'text',      'orange')

select A.* 
from @t A INNER JOIN 
    (select N.hash from @t N where N.[name_var] = 'number' and N.[value] = '5') B 
        ON A.hash = B.hash
where A.name_var = 'text' And A.value <> 'hello'
```

Answer (score 0):

Для случая если Вам надо найти несколько равенств и несколько неравенств, можно использовать следующий запрос (корректно для MySQL и Oracle, для других СУБД не проверял):

```
select hash
  from alldata T1
 where (name_var,value) in (('number','5'),('abcd','xyz'))
   and not exists(
        select 1 from alldata T2
         where T2.hash=T1.hash
           and (T2.name_var,T2.value) in (('text','hello'),('text','apple'),('param','2'))
   )
 group by hash
 having count(1)=2
```

Данный запрос даст все `hash` для которых есть строки с `number=5 И abcd='xyz'` при этом для которых не существует ни одной записи c: `text='hello' или text='apple' или param!='2'`.

Число `2` в строке `having count(1)=2` - это количество условий которые должны совпасть в первой части sql запроса. Оно *должно* точно соответствовать количеству различных name_var, упомянутых в первой части запроса.

В первой части *нельзя* в `in` указывать проверку одного и того же поля на несколько разных значений. Если такое встречается, то in, написанный для удобства, надо разворачивать в полноценные проверки. Например в первой части для выбора `number=5 или number=6` *нельзя* написать `(name_var,value) in (('number','5'),('number','6'),('abcd','xyz'))` т.к. в этом случае `count(1)` даст неверный результат. В таком случае надо писать что то типа `( (name_var='number' and (value='5' or value='6') ) OR (name_var='abcd' and 'value'='xyz') )`

Напротив, во вложенном запросе (который в not exists) *можно* перечислять любые недопустимые значения, что и показано в основном примере.